# using -O2 decreases time of bubble sort C program

Tags: c, sorting, gcc, bubble-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort();

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        sort();
    }
}

void sort() {
    int i, j, k, array[100], l = 99, m;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 99; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if (array[j + 1] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        l--;
    }
    for (m = 0; m < 100; m++) {
        printf("%d ", array[m]);
    }
}
```

On the linux shell, `gcc sort -o sort.c` and then `time ./sort >> out`.
Here if I do `gcc -o2 sort -o sort.c` and similarly `o3` and `o4` then the time keeps on decreasing. How does the optimization options work? Please explain in terms of all real time, user time and system time.

PS: The code might be a little inefficient. Kindly ignore that.

Comment: Aren't the `-O2`, `-O3`, and `-O4` optimization options (note the upper case `O`)? So wouldn't you expect the time to decrease? I'm not sure I understand the question. And I don't think you did `gcc sort -o sort.c` as that would attempt to compile `sort` as a source and write the binary to `sort.c`. I would think you entered `gcc sort.c -o sort`?

Comment: in other words: when it comes to execution time, less is better.

Comment: @lurker sorry , the question is how do -o2, -o3 work

Comment: `-o2` tells the compiler to write its output to a file named `2`. `-O2` enables optimizations. They're entirely different options; since gcc's options are case-sensitive. Also, if you're really using `-o sort.c`, then you're clobbering your source file. Please update your question to make it clear which one you're actually using; copy-and-paste your exact shell command.

Comment: Avoid naming a variable `l` as it looks too similar to `1`, especially with fixed with fonts used in programmer's editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimization options work between the reading of the source code and the writing of the binary instructions to the CPU.

GCC is a multi-phase compiler, where the phases roughly consist of:

1. Creating "tokens" from the input text.
2. Arranging those tokens into abstract syntax tree structure.
3. Pruning the abstract syntax tree.
4. Creating register based instructions, assuming an infinite number of CPU registers.
5. Mapping the registers into the actual registers available.
6. Writing the binary information out, in the loader's expected format.

Optimizations can impact a number of locations, typically they become active in the above mentioned steps 3 through 5.  There are many optimizations, including:

- Constant folding – Evaluate constant subexpressions in advance.
- Strength reduction – Replace slow operations with faster equivalents.
- Null sequences – Delete useless operations.
- Combine operations – Replace several operations with one equivalent.
- Algebraic laws – Use algebraic laws to simplify or reorder instructions.
- Special case instructions – Use instructions designed for special operand cases.
- Address mode operations – Use address modes to simplify code.
- Loop unrolling - Replace a loop with equivalent instructions
- Partial loop unrolling - Reduce times a loop is evaluated while preserving overall function.

Note that these are not all the optimizations that might be performed, but it starts to give you an idea.

For example, if the compiler sees

```
int s = 3;
while (s < 6) {
   printf("%d\n", s);
   s++;
}
```

and the flags are set to unroll loops, then it might write CPU instructions equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n", 3);
printf("%d\n", 4);
printf("%d\n", 5);
```

Those instructions might seem more wordy to us humans, but the CPU commands might be smaller, because there is no need to "lookup" the now-erased value of `s`, nor is there the need to add one to it, or store the new updated value back into RAM.

GCC arranges the optimizations into categories, ranging from "safe" to "risky".  -O2 is a good compromise between speed and safety.  Higher -O numbers are riskier.

Comment: The main GCC frontends do not have an abstract syntax tree (in the sense that there is a tree node for a `for` statement, or one for an `if` statement).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer GCC does have an AST, not sure if it is part of what you call the front-end or not, but you can access it through `gcc -fdump-tree-vcg -g test.c`  Note that the AST is for GCC, not for the language being parsed, so I agree that there isn't a "C if-node" vs a "Java if-node".  Rather it is that AST which drives their back-end processes.  I hope this clarifies a point, which in my expression, I see was read the wrong way.  Cheers!

Comment: `-fdump-tree-vcg` used to dump the CFG, which is not an AST. Both the C and C++ front ends lower control flow constructs to `goto`s. There isn't anything which closely resembles the original syntax.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I didn't create GCC, but I've read a lot of it's design.  Yes, the AST in GCC is not a language-specific AST, but I've never claimed it was.  It is an AST designed such that the single back-end can handle a variety of language front ends.  And if  you ever program in assembly, goto has an analog in the JMP related instructions, which is the way selective flow control is typically done in assembly.

Comment: Does your last example ever produce code like `puts("3\n4\n5")`?

Comment: @chqrlie No, because loop unrolling is a single type of optimization, and that output would require a different type of optimization.  That said, your output would be a valid optimization, because the observable output would be preserved, but whether a compiler would arrive at it is heavily dependent on how much optimization is requested, and if the compiler has a routine to compact constant strings (applied after the loop unrolling).

Comment: @EdwinBuck: both `gcc` and `clang` do optimize `printf("Hello world\n");` into `puts("Hello world");` and `printf("\n");` into `(putchar)('\n');` so combining multiple `printf` statements into a single `puts` or handling conversions of constant arguments seems quite easy but for some reason not considered worthwhile.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, but do that do that in the context of a loop unrolling?  That requires multiple passes of optimization, and I didn't personally look into where the optimization stops at `-O2`.  All I said was that in the context of the loop unrolling, contenting strings is a different optimization, one which might be applied.

Answer (score 2):

`-O` stands for `optimize`, in which `gcc` will automatically take the steps necessary to optimize your program. You can read more about the specific steps that GCC takes to optimize your program here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

But essentially, `-O2` is more optimized than `-O1`, and `-O3` more than `-O2`. This might come with drawbacks in regard to compiled binary size, where the resulting binary could use more space, but run faster, and vice versa. You can actually paste your code into https://godbolt.org/, and write in `-O1` or any of the optimization options beside the dropdown to choose a compiler, and `godbolt` will show you what the resulting code looks like. You will be able to see a difference between `O1` and `O2`, namely, the `O2` generated code is probably shorter and will use a lot of shortcuts to do your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The `-O` compiler flag controls the amount of compiler optimization that you wish the compiler to perform. In short, building the project will take longer but the resulting executable should be faster. For more information, type `man gcc` into the command prompt or `gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers` for specific information regarding the optimizations performed for a particular flag.

Answer (score 1):

gcc offers a number of optimization flags. You can see what each one does specifically here:

```
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html
```

There's always a tradeoff with optimizations, either by increased compile time, increased use of memory, etc...

There are dozens of optimizations enabled by the -o2 flag, so it might not be immediately clear which specific ones affect the sorting. Instead of -o2, you can try each optimization individually, for example using the -falign-loops flag, to see whether that is the one providing the performance increase.